# How to create a Datadog monitor for Kubernetes container restarts strictly due to OOM?

Tags: kubernetes, datadog

Currently running a monitor on any kubernetes container restarts:

```
max(last_10m):monotonic_diff(default_zero(sum:kubernetes.containers.restarts{kube_namespace:production} by {kube_stateful_set})) > 0
```

I'd like to see some information about the reason - specifically OOM restarts.

Answer (score 0):

Too help folks in the future - if you are using docker as the container engine [most are circa 2022, default for EKS, etc] then you need to suss out OOM information from docker metrics, not kubernetes metrics.  k8s hands off the memory limit to the docker engine and thats it - there is no event back to kubernetes from docker.